# MySQL Check existence of a set of fields in a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am validating the existence of a set of field values (Eg: yyy,aaa and ccc) in a table and am using UNION to gather my results, would prefer a more elegant and efficient solution:

**TableName**: Example_Table

**Name | Class**

```
xxx  | CSE <BR>
yyy  | EE  <BR>
zzz  | MECH <BR>
aaa  | CSE  <BR>
bb   | CSE <BR>
```

My Query:

```
SELECT  IF(Name  IS NULL,"yyy ","")   
FROM Example_Table where (Name  LIKE '%yyy%') 
      UNION   
(SELECT  IF(Name  IS NULL,"aaa  ","")   
FROM Example_Table where (Name  LIKE '%aaa%')) 
      UNION   
(SELECT  IF(Name  IS NULL,"ccc ","")   
FROM Example_Table where (Name  LIKE '%ccc%'));
```

I need to know which of the string values I need are not present in the table. The problem is, the table I am using has around thousands of tuples and using UNION seems very costly..

Answer (score 0):

Looking for strings is never elegant ;) But if you want to shorten up your code, give `IN` a try. Something similar to...

`...WHERE Name IN ('yyy','aaa','ccc')....`

Comment: Thanks for reply...but I also need to know which of the strings are present and which are not!!